# How do i load a method in a master blade template?

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-blade

i am using laravel's blade template and i have a master template for all my pages. In the master template i have a top bar and a sidebar. I want to load something in the sidebar. But i don't know how do it in a simpler way. Now i am calling that method (which i want in to display in my sidebar) in every controller i have like this:

```
View::make()->with('data_to_load_in_sidebar',$data_to_load_in_sidebar)
```

How can i load this only once, not every time i generate a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what view composers are for, any view that is loaded will automatically have it's composer run alongside providing the view with any extra data it may require.

```
View::composer(array('partials.sidebar'), function($view) 
{
    $news = News::all();

    $view->with('news', $news);
});
```

I typically put this in my `routes.php` file in both L3 and L4.

In the view `views\partials\sidebar.blade.php` you now always have access to the variable `$news` that will contain all models from the News collection.

Answer (score 1):

I would share top bar & sidebar data in constructor (prefferably in some BaseController's contructor, that other controllers extends).

```
public function __construct()
{
    // if needed, call parent's contructor method as well
    parent::__construct()

    $data_to_load_in_sidebar = loadDataForSidebar();
    View::share('data_to_load_in_sidebar',$data_to_load_in_sidebar)
}
```